# React: How to update fetch with new query

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I was trying to change query so what i am fetching would update, but it only updates  i put there for testing. I would really appreciate help. And is it better to use this class method or learn using hooks? Since when i was googling i found something of a solution, but it was using hooks.

```
    class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      search: '',
      photos: [],
      query: 'space'
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    
    const {query} = this.state
  try{
    const responseSearch = await client.photos.search({query, per_page: 20 });
    const dataSearch = await responseSearch.photos;
    console.log(responseSearch)
    this.setState({photos: dataSearch})
    if (responseSearch.ok) {
      throw Error(responseSearch.statusText);
    }
  }catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  }
  handleClick(){
    this.setState({query: 'nature'})
  }
 

render() {
  const {photos, search, query} = this.state;
  const filteredImages = photos.filter( card =>
     card.photographer.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase() )
  ) 
  
      return (
      <div className="App">
      <Particles className ='particles'
       params={particlesOptions}
       />
       <h2>{query}</h2>
       <button onClick={this.handleClick}>change</button>
       <Nav 
       categories={categories} 
       />
      <SearchBox  
          placeholder='search cards'
          handleChange={e => this.setState({query: e.target.value})}
        />
        <CardGroup cards={filteredImages} />
      </div>
     );  
}
}
```

Comment: so you want to ReFetch data when the query changes?

Comment: So initially my query is "space" and after i press button i want it to update to well in my case nature, so i would now see photos of nature. but i only managed to update <h2>

Comment: checkout my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another lifecycle method called `componentDidUpdate` which will get invoked whenever a `props` or `state` is changed (note that this does not get called initially when the component is rendered so you will still have to use `componentDidMount`).

And then you can shift your API call in a separate method (let's call it `fetchData`) and reuse it in both `componentDidMount` as well as `componentDidUpdate` so your code will look something like below:

```
fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const responseSearch = await client.photos.search({ query, per_page: 20 });
    const dataSearch = await responseSearch.photos;
    console.log(responseSearch)
    this.setState({ photos: dataSearch })
    if (responseSearch.ok) {
      throw Error(responseSearch.statusText);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchData();
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  // have a condition to avoid infinite fetchData calls
  if (prevState.query !== this.state.query) {
    this.fetchData();
  }
}
```

Comment: Man i love u, thank u so much, it was so frustrating and took so much time thinking about it. since i somewhy did not want to ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

Fetching will not update if you put it into the lifecycle method `componentDidMount`. It is not okay to put the fetch into render. You better trigger a fetch method after `setState` is done.

```
handleClick(){
   this.setState({query: 'nature'},this.fetchAgain)
}
fetchAgain(){
   const {query} = this.state
   try{
       const responseSearch = await client.photos.search({query, per_page: 20 });
       const dataSearch = await responseSearch.photos;
       console.log(responseSearch)
       this.setState({photos: dataSearch})
       if (responseSearch.ok) {
           throw Error(responseSearch.statusText);
        }
       }catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a method that fetches the data `fetchData`, then I would call that method in `componentDidMount` and I would create another method to handle query changes and call `fetchData` after the state updated

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
}

fetchData = () => {
      ... //fetch code
}

changeQuery = (query) => { 
    this.setState({query : query} , this.fetchData);
}

render() { 
   ...
   <SearchBox  
      placeholder='search cards'
      handleChange={e => this.changeQuery(e.target.value)}
    />

   ...
}
```

you want to disable the input while the fetching happening